# Get file extension with preg_replace

Tags: regex, preg-replace

How can I get a file's extension with `preg_replace`? What is the correct `regex` to solve this problem?

```
$test = "picture.jpeg";

$ret = preg_replace("/(\.[\w]+)$/", "$1", $test);
echo $ret;    //expected output: jpeg
```

Comment: What do you mean files ending with `preg_replace`? How can files end with a function!

Comment: in this example the file ending is: `.jpeg`

Comment: So basically you want to get the extension of a file?

Comment: Yes, sorry i don't know how to call it in english.

Comment: Just put the dot before the opening parenthesis: `/\.(\w+)$/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the extension of any file, use this regex:

`.*?\.(.*)$`

Run it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/lR2lZ4/1)

This `regex` can be used in `preg_replace()`

EDIT:

Even though the explanation is available at the link, I put the same here on OP's request:

a. `.*?`lazily matches any character (except newline) 
b. `\.` matches the character `.` literally 
c. `(.*)$` everything till the end of the input (represented by `$`) is then captured in the first capturing group.

Comment: It doesn't work if the filename is `pict.ure.jpeg`. `.*?` is superfluous and extension is at least one character, not zero.